# Configure OpenVPN client to use a different gateway

Tags: openvpn

Given:

- A computer running Manjaro Linux, with a gateway of 192.168.1.11, that routes all traffic through a personal VPN.
- For work, there is an ovpn file from the employer for connecting to the work network. There is no access to the OpenVPN server parameters. The server configuration is such that only work domains go through the VPN.
- There is a gateway 192.168.1.1, where there are no VPNs.

How can I make the work OpenVPN traffic not go through the default gateway 192.168.1.11, but through 192.168.1.1?

In other words, how can I make the work VPN traffic not go through the personal VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Find inside your employer's VPN configuration the line containing `remote`, to which the VPN connects to, resolve it to an IP address, and create a route (as root) for that specific host only:

```
ip route add A.B.C.D via 192.168.1.1
```

Please note that the above route will not survive a reboot, so do not forget to make that route persistent if you want to keep it permanently.